# Compare the results of a bunch of SQL statements and review results

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with 2 columns. Column 1 is Query_Name and column 2 is Query_Text. This query_text column contains a semi-simple SQL Select statement. I have 34 rows like this. These Select statements are not necessarily operating on the same SQL server. I want a way where I can run these 34 queries, compare their result, and notify the user via email if certain conditions apply. The email part, I got that. It is a SQL server agent task. But I am lost as to how to run these 34 queries and compare them.

This has to be dynamic. For instance, a stored procedure with 34 variables won't work. This 34 might be 40 tomorrow. I want to run the queries contained in the query_text column every night and compare them and email the user.

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

The comparison part: It cannot be significantly different. What is significantly different is determined by my boss. For the sake of this question, let us just assume it cannot vary by more than 100. The output of these 34 queries are numbers (Their data type might be nvarchar, but the output is definitely numbers).

EDIT 2:

RUN 1 query that in turn runs all the queries in a given column.

```
DECLARE @QUERYCOLUMN nvarchar(50)
SET @QUERYCOLUMN = (SELECT QUERY_TEXT FROM TABLE_NAME)
EXEC(@QUERYCOLUMN)
```

Something in that fashion.

Comment: the question is far too broad, what does `run 34 queries and compare them` mean?, compare what?, how?

Comment: sounds like you want some sort of BI solution or analysis and reporting tool?

Comment: Can't you load every statement into a list? That should be enough to make it dynamic. You know the count and the statements then.

Comment: Is the question just about how to dynamically run the queries - i.e. you have in mind how you will do the comparison(s)?  Have you looked at selecting from your table, iterating over the cursor, and using `sp_executesql()` for each query string?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger This question is basically this: How to run ONE query, that in turn runs EVERY query in a particular column. Forget about the comparison part, even. Just run a query that runs all the queries in the query_text column and returns the result to the user.

Comment: @Cataklysim I had thought about that, but I think something would stop me from doing that. I forgot what it was. I will get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dumps your queries into a table variable and loops through them executing the text then deleting it from the table variable. You should definately be aware of the dangers of executing dynamic SQL before adopting this or any other approach though.

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50), @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Queries TABLE (Query_Name VARCHAR(50), Query_Text VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Queries(Query_Name, Query_Text)
SELECT Query_Name, Query_Text FROM MY_SOURCE_TABLE

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Queries)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @Name = Query_Name, @Query = Query_Text FROM @Queries
EXEC(@Query)
DELETE FROM @Queries WHERE Query_Name = @Name
END
```

This method assumes Query_Name is unique in your source data or else the results could be skewed.

Comment: Running this right now. Will mark as answer when it is done running. It is going to take at least 15 minutes to run each of those select statements and return a result. Seems promising though, thank you.

Comment: OK, it isn't done running yet but I have a question for you.

The result of this is supposed to be a table with 34 rows. The 34 rows are numbers. If I wanted to compare each of these rows to every other row in the database, how would I do that? 
I want to take row 1 and compare to rows 2-34. Take row 2 and compare it to row 1, row 3-34. So on.. I basically want to see a difference between the rows. If difference between row 1 and row 22 is a 102, i must notify the user. If the difference between row 17 and row 12, I must notify the user.

Comment: The results of my query will be 34 independant result sets. For what you are asking the best option would be to add an insert statement above the EXEC(@Query) and then after the END add your comparison script.

Something Like:

INSERT INTO My_Results_Table (Query_Name, Results)
EXEC(@Query)

Then after the END you would have some conditional code to compare the results.

Comment: 20 minutes and 32 seconds to run that query, but it is finally done. Exactly what I wanted. So, to make sure I understood you, Insert these 34 returned rows into a table and compare it? Also, I have 35 different panes in my output window. 1st one is 34 rows with "1" in it. I am assuming that is from the `select 1 from @queries` statement. Would removing that statement hurt anything? Because I think comparison would be complicated with a bunch of 1s in the beginning of the table.

Comment: Haha no sorry I removed it as soon as I had posted it but not quick enough clearly!

Comment: LOL. Thanks anyway. This works perfectly. Now I have to figure out a way to compare them and wait 20 minutes every time I want to test them. Haha

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to iterate through the table and execute the statements contained in each entry.

You will need to alter the statement contained in @sSQL if you wish to output this into a table, but this will work for testing in SSMS for you.

I would suggest you use a simple incrementing ID of sorts (Identity is the easiest) to allow you determine when all entries have been accounted for.

```
DECLARE @QID INT, @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @QID = MIN(QID) FROM [dbo].[QueryComparison]
WHILE @QID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SELECT @sSQL = Query_Text FROM [dbo].[QueryComparison] WHERE QID = @QID
EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL

SELECT @QID = MIN(QID) FROM [dbo].[QueryComparison] WHERE QID > @QID

END
```